# De-Convolution of Distributions

Tags: convolution, unimodality

Under what conditions a continuous unimodal distribution G(x) can be represented as a convolution of N of the same F(x) distributions?

I.e. G(x)= F(x) * F(x) * F(x) *......

Also does F(x) also have to be unimodal?

Comment: @CarloBeenakker I guess an arbitrary $N$-th root is not guaranteed to give a real, non-negative function?

Comment: I had missed the condition that $F(x)$ should be itself a distribution, apologies.

Answer (score 4):

The answer to the second question, "does $F(x)$ have to be unimodal if the convolution with itself is unimodal" is negative. A counterexample from this [note](https://www.cmu.edu/biolphys/deserno/pdf/uncorrelated-sum-pdensity.pdf) is 
$$F(x)=\frac{1+x^2}{\sqrt{8\pi}}e^{-x^2/2}$$
$$\Rightarrow G(x)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty F(y)F(x-y)\,dx=\frac{x^4+4x^2+44}{128\sqrt{\pi}}e^{-x^2/4}.$$

[image]
the blue curve is $F(x)$, the gold curve is $G(x)$.

---

Concerning the first question, a sufficient condition for the deconvolution of a unimodal distribution into $N$ identical distributions to exist *for any $N$* is given in [Unimodality of Infinitely Divisible Distribution Functions of Class L](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aop/1176995474) (M. Yamazato, 1978).